# Looking for Proofs on Finding the Roots of an Algebraic Congruence with a Composite Modulus

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for proofs that verify the following procedure for finding the roots of an algebraic congruence with a composite modulus. Upon reading Oystein Ore's Number Theory and it's History, I came across a procedure for finding all the solutions of an algebraic congruence of the form f(x) = 0 ( mod m ) when f(x) is a polynomial and m is a composite which involves substituting all the positive residues [ 0 .. (m-1) ] or least absolute residues [ - m/2 .. m/2 ] in the congruence. All of the roots, x0, found from this procedure form a set of solutions for the congruence of the form x = x0 (mod m ). This was the procedure given in Ore's book in the section called Analysis of Congruences. I have also found some PDFs online covering number theory which state the same thing, but, I would like it if I could find a few proofs of the accuracy of this procedure. Can anyone recommend abook or paper with such a proof? I am skeptical of the completeness of this procedure. It seems naive assuming that their is not another member of Z+ which satisfies f(x) = 0 ( mod m ) when none of its residues satisfy it.

Also, could someone explain whether there is a difference in using the positive residues or least absolute residues. Will the solution set be the same? It should be. Can anyone recommend any texts with proofs of this?

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: The fact we get all solutions follows from the fact that if $a\equiv a'\pmod{m}$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod{p}$, then $a+b\equiv a'+b'\pmod{m}$ and $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod{m}$. Polynomials are built up using addition and multiplication. As to positive residues or least absolute residues, the results will be the same (modulo $m$). Least absolute residues can be useful because the arithmetic may be easier, and one can take advantage of $\pm$ symmetries.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question follows by the Polynomial Congruence Rule below  Namely, if $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients then $\ A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, f(A)\equiv f(a),\,$ so $\,f(A)\equiv 0\!\iff\!f(a)\equiv 0.\, $ So to enumerate all roots it suffices to test all $\,x\,$ from any *complete* system of remainders mod $\,m.\,$

Any sequence of $\,m\,$ consecutive integers is a complete system of remainders mod $\,m.\,$ This has a simple proof by induction:  shifting such a sequence  by one does not change its set of remainders mod $\,m,\,$ since it replaces one (extreme) element by a  congruent element $\:\color{#C00}a\leftrightarrow \color{#C00}{a+m}$

$$\begin{array}{}& \color{#C00}a, &\!\!\!\! a+1, &\!\!\!\! a+2, &\!\!\!\! \cdots, &\!\!\!\! a+m-1  & \\
                  \leftrightarrow & &\!\!\!\! a+1,&\!\!\!\! a+2, &\!\!\!\! \cdots, &\!\!\!\! a+m-1, &\!\!\!\! \color{#C00}{a+m} \end{array}\qquad$$

Since $\: \color{#C00}{a\,\equiv\, a\!+\!m}\pmod m,\:$ the shift does not change the remainders in the sequence. Thus, by induction, the set of remainders is the same as the base case $\ 0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\ =\: $ *all* $ $ possible remainders mod $\,m\,$ (by the Division Algorithm).  The balanced or least absolute value remainder system is a special case of this.  It often proves handy because its minimal magnitude remainders simplify  computations, and its innate reflection symmetry $\,n\mapsto -n\,$ [often simplifies problems.](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+++reflection+symmetry+mod)

---

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c0f}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c0f}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{blue}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{blue}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\qquad \color{}{A\equiv a}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{A^n\equiv a^n}\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1}},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Polynomial Congruence Rule** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is polynomial with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\, n = $ degree $f.\,$ Clear if $\, n = 0.\,$ Else $\,f(x) = f(0) + x\,g(x)\,$ for $\,g(x)\,$ a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $< n.\,$  By induction $\,g(A)\equiv g(a)\,$ so $\, A g(A)\equiv a g(A)\,$ by the Product Rule. Hence $\,f(A) = f(0)+Ag(A)\equiv f(0)+ag(a) = f(a)\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).